# i want to get woocommerce thumbnail src url in array

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want get thumbnail image url in the following image attribute

```
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID ); //do this instead
    $end_point   = 'https://api.webpushr.com/v1/notification/send/sid';

    //do a wp_remote_post instead of cURL

    $body = array(
        'title'      => $product->get_name(),
        'message'    => 'check out now',
        'target_url' => $product->get_permalink(),
        'image'      => $product->get_image($attr = array( 'src'=>get_the_post_thumbnail_url())), // Here I want to get Image thumbnail url. But it is not working
        'sid'        => '113858026',
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

`'image' => wp_get_attachment_image_url( $product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail' )`

where you get the image id using `$product->get_image_id()` then you use `wp_get_attachment_image_url` to get the url.

Comment: It is Not working